# How do I add the first ietm in the lists to the first item in the second list

Tags: python, list

Hi I am very new to programing and coding but I think I am doing pretty good for only a month so far. I have hit a little snag and ran into a problem I do not know how to solve. I have two separate text files that I am taking numbers from and averaging them together and putting the average in a new file. The two text files are zztext.txt & zztext2.txt. There is not the number list like 1), 2), 3), 4), or 5) in the files I did it two show what is on what line number.

This is what is in the zztext.txt:

1. P3
2. 591 600
3. 255
4. 1 4 3
5. 4 5 6

This is what is in the zztext2.txt:

1. P3
2. 591 600
3. 255
4. 6 5 4
5. 4 2 6

```
import os
a = 0
#progarm1-program4 needs name changes
def program1():
    print(os.getcwd())
    
    inFile = open('zztext.txt','r')
    for i in range(3):
        next (inFile)
    inFile2 = open('zztext2.txt','r')
    for i in range(3):
        next (inFile2)
        
    for line in inFile:
        first1 = line.split()
        print(first1)
        print(first1[a])
        
    print('\n')
        
    for line in inFile2:
        first2 = line.split()
        print(first2)
        print(first2[a])
    
        
    #change [number] to go across
    w = int(first1[a]) + int(first2[a])
    print(w)
```

result =
['**1**', '**4**', '3'] This returns 1

['4', '5', '6'] This returns 4

['**6**', '**5**', '4'] This returns 6

['4', '2', '6'] This returns 4 and the final return is 8 because the 4 and 4 from both lists were added together.

I want the bold 1 and 6 added together and the bold 4 and 5 added together and both put in a new file so it would look like:

1. P3
2. 591 600
3. 255
4. 7(1 and 6 added) 9(4 and 5 added) and 7(3 and 4 added)
   and then the next row of numbers
5. 8(4+4) 7(5+2) 12(6+6)
   and so on. Any help would be greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.
Your posted code defines a function and quits without calling it.
Don't expect us to enter test data, or to build a test file.
Instead, simply hard-code a test case that shows the problem.

Answer (score 1):

So you are on the right path, just a few small tweaks needed to get you what you want.

```
def program():
    with open("zztext.txt","r") as f1, open("zztext2.txt", "r") as f2:
        for _ in range(3):
            next(f1)
            next(f2)
        while True:
            try:
                l1 = next(f1)
                l2 = next(f2)
            except StopIteration:
                break
            xs = map(int, l1.split())
            ys = map(int, l2.split())
            
            result = [sum(t) for t in zip(xs, ys)]
            print(result)
```

This prints:

```
[7, 9, 7]
[8, 7, 12]
```

I would also suggest breaking your code in to smaller functions. Separate functions that open files, that do the logic, etc..

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to coing and python! Here is the full program, checkout what details you are missing, feel free to ask if you have any questions about my version of the program

```
def read_file(filename): #returns a list with each line with newline removed
    return [line.strip() for line in open(filename, 'r').readlines()]

def all_digits(string): #returns true if all characters are digits in string
    return all([char.isdigit() for char in string.split(' ')])

def split_string(string): #returns a list with int of each character in the string
    return [int(char) for char in string.split(' ')]

def program(file_1, file_2, outfile):
    output = []
    for line_file1, line_file2 in zip(read_file(file_1), read_file(file_2)):
        if all([not line_file1 == line_file2, all_digits(line_file1), all_digits(line_file2)]):
            #if lines don't match and they characters are digits in string 
            print(f'found digits {line_file1} and {line_file2}, adding their sum to the file..')
            new_line = []
            for digit1, digit2 in zip(split_string(line_file1), split_string(line_file2)):
                new_line.append(str(digit1+digit2))
            new_line = ' '.join(new_line)
        else:
            print(f'adding non-digit line {line_file1} to the file')
            new_line = line_file1
        output.append(new_line)
    output_lines =  '\n'.join(output)

    open(outfile, "w").write(output_lines)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    program("zztext.txt", "zztext2.txt", "output.txt")
```

You should read about [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) and [all](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) functions, they are neat